# Xamarin forms - remove all borders/shadows from boxview or frame

Tags: xamarin.forms, border, shadow

```
<Frame
                    Grid.Row="3"
                    Grid.RowSpan="2"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                    BackgroundColor="White"
                    CornerRadius="20"
                    HasShadow="False"
                    BorderColor="White"
                    HeightRequest="20" />
```

I was wondering if it's possible to remove all border / shadow effects from the BoxView / Frame? See the straight faint gray line in picture. When I draw a white boxview or frame, it always seems to show a faint gray border/shadow when superimposed on a white page. But I just want it to blend in perfectly with the white page background, so that it's invisible.  I tried setting BorderColor='White', and HasShadow="false" on the frame. There is no property called borderwidth. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: If you set border color to Transparent it can't be shown by design. If it still shows then it is a bug, on android that could happen if you set elevation of another view and that elevation is applied to your view creating a pseudo dropshadow effect

Comment: Thanks, these are some good ideas. I will let you know if it fixes it.

Comment: Wow, marking BorderColor as transparent seems to have worked! Please write your comment as the answer to this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you set border color to `Transparent` it can't be shown by design.

If it still shows then it is a bug, on android that could happen if you set elevation of another view and that elevation is applied to your view creating a pseudo dropshadow effect